# Create a Spark SQL query filtering by values in dataframe

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I'm a beginner in Scala and spark and can't find an answer to this anywhere. I have a Spark DF with client IDs, and I want to use these ids in a SQL query on an external database. For example:

`sc.sql("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE client_id IN (DF_CLIENT_ID)")`

How can I concatenate the values in the DF with my SQL query?

Comment: you probably can't combine Spark dataframes with external (non-Spark/Hive) databases with sc.sql ... may need JDBC for this

Comment: It's a Hive DB, but it's on an external server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Approach 1

Since you intend to run the query in your external database with data from your spark dataframe, you will have to persist your results from your spark dataframe outside of spark as your external database would not be able to directly access this data, especially since spark usually tries to operate in memory and the data may be partitioned across many nodes.

I recommend persisting the data to your external database as a temp/table or materialized view and running your query from there. If data in the spark dataframe changes frequently you may run this frequently using a job/scheduler of your choice.

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE client_id IN (select DF_CLIENT_ID from tempTable)
```

## Approach 2

This is probably easier, to do everything in spark.

1. create a second dataframe pulling from your external database
2. merge or perform any operations in spark
3. persist the results to a location of your choosing (this could be back to the external database)

```scala
 sc.sql("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE client_id IN (select DF_CLIENT_ID from tempTable)"
```

Comment: very nice response, I was thinking about the second approach. As I have a data stream, I would select * from my external database, create a DF, and update this persistent DF with new data from Stream to keep it updated and don't need to crate a new select query!

Comment: But, I thought that what I want was very simple. For example, in Python, I would just get all IDs from DF, transform it on a tuple and pass this tuple concatenating a string in the query. Ex ` sc.sql("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE client_id IN (PYTHON_TUPLE)")`. Its not possible to do this in scala?

Comment: @AlvaroLeandroCavalcante You can perform approach 2 as you suggested similar to your python. From the question, I did not assume what was stored in `DF_CLIENT_ID`. If `DF_CLIENT_ID` is a single/list of values that when included in the sql string is still a valid sql statement. This will still work

Comment: I gave you an example in Python because is the language that I know, but I'm programming in scala. I have a DF if a lot of information, but I filtered my ids with ```client_id = DF.select("ID")```
Now, I want to pass this list of ID's into my SQL query to create a valid query!

Comment: @AlvaroLeandroCavalcante  `client_id_string = DF.select("ID").collect().mkString(",")` would get the ids, and collect them into an integer array and finally combine them into a comma separated string

Comment: Awesome! I got an array of IDs, like "[2314],[2131]..." that's almost what I want! There's some way to get the string without an array?

Comment: `client_id_string = DF.select("ID").collect().flatMap(_.toList).mkString(",")`. The flatmap will flatten this array before making the final string

Comment: The FlatMap gave me an error, but I used this and worked ```DF.select("ID").collect().map(x => x.getString(0)).mkString(",")```, Thnak you!